# 'this.response' is not printing in the console

Tags: javascript, http, xmlhttprequest, httprequest, httpresponse

```
    function callOtherDomain() {

        var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var username = "usr";
        var password = "pass";
        var url = 'https://someurl';  
        invocation.open('GET', url, true, username,password);  
        console.log(this.responseText);                                
        invocation.send();
    }
```

**I am not able to get the response working for the code above**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, `responseText` is the response you get from the `XMLHttpRequest`, so it should naturally be a member of `invocation` and not `this`.

Secondly, since it's the response of the request, there won't be anything before there have been an actual response received. So if the request was synchronous then you could do it after the `send` call. Unfortunately you do it as an asynchronous request, which means you have to create a response handler (using the [`onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) property) and print the response when the response have been fully received.

I suggest you follow the link on the [`onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) property, as it contains a very simple but good example on how to handle async requests, doing exactly what you want.

Comment: should it be console.log(invocation.response) ?

Comment: "Secondly, since it's the response of the request, there won't be anything before the request has actually been sent.".

Do not know what's behind invocation, but we can imagine than open actually return a promise.

Did you know what's going on behind that? If this is a promise as well, then you should do something like invocation.open().then(function() { console.log([this, invocation].response); }) Depending on your implementation, callback could be called with a defined this (throught call or apply), and this will refer to invocation object itself.

Comment: @xyzsfdc To start with, yes. But since the request is *asynchronous* there won't actually be anything to print until after the request is done. If you change to make it synchronous then you can print after the `send` call, otherwise you have to do it in the handler function.

Comment: @Nico -         invocation.open('GET', url, true, username,password).then(function() { console.log([this, invocation].response); }) ;   is not working

Comment: @Nico No, [`open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open%28%29) doesn't return anything.